Flutter MissingPluginException using Android code and FCM
I want to start some native code in Android when I receive a firebase message (FCM), but I get this error:
E/flutter (16352): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method wakeUpApp on channel com.diesetelecom.smartdiese.androidChannel)
E/flutter (16352): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:332:7)
E/flutter (16352): <asynchronous suspension>

I already try to uninstall the app -> flutter clean -> flutter pub get -> flutter run
but unsuccessfully
Here is my code in flutter in my main.dart, I tried to remove "com.diesetelecom.smartdiese" to keep "androidChannel" but i'm still having the error.
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  ...
  const MethodChannel androidChannel = MethodChannel('com.diesetelecom.smartdiese.androidChannel');
  androidChannel.invokeMethod("wakeUpApp");
}

Future<void> main() async { 
    ...

    FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

    ...

  await AssetsManager.initAssets();

  await dotenv.load();

  runApp(const App());
}

Here is my MainActivity.kt, knowing that I have this error when I try to call the Android method from the firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler but it works outside
package com.diesetelecom.smart_diese

import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.media.AudioManager
import androidx.annotation.NonNull
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel
import android.util.Log

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    private val CHANNEL = "androidChannel"

    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
        MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
            if (call.method == "switchAudioOutput") {
                val audioManager: AudioManager = getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
                audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL)
                audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(!audioManager.isSpeakerphoneOn)
                result.success(audioManager.isSpeakerphoneOn)
            } else if(call.method == "wakeUpApp") {
                Log.d("ActivityMain", "This is a small test text")
                result.success(true)
            } else {
                result.notImplemented()
            }
        }
    }
}



I noticed an issue in your MainActivity.kt file. You've created a top level variable named as CHANNEL as private val CHANNEL = "androidChannel".
Please keep in mind that your method channel name should be synced in both of the platforms i.e. in Flutter and Kotlin or Swift. You're trying to invoke wakeUpApp method from Flutter platform with method channel name com.diesetelecom.smartdiese.androidChannel while in Kotlin there is no method channel with this name as you're setting channel name in android as androidChannel That's why there is no implementation against the name you're specifying in Flutter code.
You should try below code in order to make it run:
Flutter Side:
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  ...
  const MethodChannel androidChannel = MethodChannel('com.diesetelecom.smartdiese.androidChannel');
  androidChannel.invokeMethod("wakeUpApp");
}

Future<void> main() async { 
    ...

    FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

    ...

  await AssetsManager.initAssets();

  await dotenv.load();

  runApp(const App());
}

Kotlin Side:
package com.diesetelecom.smart_diese

import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.media.AudioManager
import androidx.annotation.NonNull
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel
import android.util.Log

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    private val CHANNEL = "com.diesetelecom.smartdiese.androidChannel"

    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
        MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
            if (call.method == "switchAudioOutput") {
                val audioManager: AudioManager = getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
                audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL)
                audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(!audioManager.isSpeakerphoneOn)
                result.success(audioManager.isSpeakerphoneOn)
            } else if(call.method == "wakeUpApp") {
                Log.d("ActivityMain", "This is a small test text")
                result.success(true)
            } else {
                result.notImplemented()
            }
        }
    }
}


You're right i modified this while trying to debug it, but the error is not coming from here. The thing I don't understand is when i use the androidChannel.invokeMethod("wakeUpApp"); in the main function, it works, but not in the background handler

Yes, because in background handler MainActivity.kt is not yet initialized and so your channels as well.

Can you please let me know, what you're trying to achieve?

I'm trying to bring the app to foreground when I receive a firebase message because i'm developing an app to receive calls from a raspberry

And I couldn't find anything about it in flutter so I'm trying to do it with native code

@JoelNogues opening app from an invalid channel i.e. from background without taking permission from user will lead to serious concerns on user data privacy policy
